# is there any method to draw a tree with a root , the root's previous nodes and successor nodes?

Tags: d3.js

In d3.js, i find that the tree layout cannot calculate the previous nodes by a certain node, it only can draw the successor nodes. is that some layout  like DAG can be draw in d3.js?

Comment: Explain what DAG is, please.

Comment: The directed acyclic graph

Comment: If you mean _directed acyclic graphs_ maybe the tree layout in d3.js isn't your best option. Consider the directed force diagram: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045

Comment: Also, what do you mean with _calculate the previous nodes by a certain node_?

Comment: I wanna to display the hierarchy level in such tree graph.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of ideas you might find useful:

You can use the tree layout to place the nodes in the canvas, create link objects pointing back and forth, then bind the link objects to a diagonal.

http://www.durablejs.org/examples/flowchart/1/admin.html

You can also use place the nodes using a pack layout, create the link objects pointing back and forth, and bind the links to a Bezier curve.

http://www.durablejs.org/examples/statechart/1/admin.html

You can find the code for the graphs above:

https://github.com/jruizgit/durable/tree/master/lib/durabjevisual.js